# Using deleteLater into constructor of QObject-derived class

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, dbus, networkmanager

[Example code is here.](https://github.com/tomilov/networkmanager)

I found something that looks like an idiom for properties of pointer type in C++ objects exported to *QML*. Pointee for these properties can cease to exist at any time due to external events occurrence. I use `QObject::deleteLater` slot for this purposes. `<property>Changed` signal (required by QML) can be connected to `QObject::destroyed` signal. I have noted that at the moment of emitting of this signal `QPointer` is already clear. So property value will be valid on QML side at right moment.

Looking through `QPointer` header I note it is based on `QWeakPointer`/`QSharedPointer` and seems used behaviour (i.e. "`QPointer` became clear before calling of a first slot connected to `destroyed` signal") is somehow hard-set, though not specified in documentation.

In my case properties are pointers to `QDBusAbstractInterface`-derived classes [[1](https://github.com/tomilov/networkmanager/blob/master/networkmanagerinterface.hpp#L56)] which corresponds to *NetworkManager* *D-Bus* service interfaces. *NetworkManager* *D-Bus* service can be unexpectedly unregistered and all above classes became unusable and `QDBusAbstractInterface::isValid()` for each of them became `false`.

During lifetime of `QDBusAbstractInterface`-derived classes after creation of them I can manage such a situation by means of `QDBusServiceWatcher` watcher.

But during creation of `QDBusAbstractInterface`-derived class I can't rely on service availability. Even if I check availability of the service by means of `QDBusConnection::systemBus().interface()->isServiceRegistered(QStringLiteral(NM_DBUS_SERVICE))` it immediately can became unavailable right before next operator (in terms of C++). Therefore constructed class can be unusable (i.e. `QDBusAbstractInterface::isValid()` is `false`) right after construction of its `QDBusAbstractInterface` base.

What I currently do is calling `deleteLater()` [[2](https://github.com/tomilov/networkmanager/blob/master/networkmanager.hpp#L82)] into the constructor depending on `isValid()`. At my mind this eventually leads to destruction of object right after its construction as soon as event loop will be reached.

Is it permittable to call `deleteLater()` slot in constructor of `QObject`-derived class?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it permittable to call deleteLater() slot in constructor of
>   QObject-derived class?

That is just unusual and unobvious (the class consumer may not expect it) way to dispose of an invalid object and we can always detect if the instance of the class cannot be valid before creating it with the pattern of class-factory:

```
class MyNetworkManager
{
public:
   // static create method
   static MyNetworkManager* create();

private:
   // private constructor
   MyNetworkManager();
};

/*static*/ MyNetworkManager* MyNetworkManager::create()
{
   // This method may contain all the necessary logic
   // to avoid producing an invalid class instance.
   if (nwkSystem.isReady())
       retrun new MyNetworkManager;

   return nullptr;
}

// usage would be
auto* p = MyNetworkManager::create();
if (!p)
{
    qDebug() << "the system is not ready for MyNetworkManager";
}
```

Comment: Seems you poorly read the question. In your answer between execution of `nwkSystem.isReady()` and `new MyNetworkManager` the former one can became `false`. I specifically pointed to this.

Comment: @Orient, of course the answer is deliberately simple but you can make sure with the code the same way as in constructor but not in constructor. I looked at your code,

Comment: ... and if the instance of the class becomes invalid during its life time then the signal can be emitted to the consumer of the class and deleteLater() would be some implicit misleading action then.

Comment: I agree. Seems it is better to check `isValid()` right after construction and apply `delete` to raw pointer.

Comment: ...and not assign new value via `setProperty` before this check.

Comment: One after another... I like KDE QtNetworkManager as it is more adequate for Linux but it is not sufficient for me so I use it for certain things while all the network traffic is handled via Qt own QNetwork* stuff.

Comment: NetworkManager is for system administration, QtNetwork is for another things, I think.

Comment: Me too. And it is not easy at all after reading of NetworkManager D-Bus API docs and QDBus. It is very hard to manage, say, Wi-Fi connections correctly.

Comment: BTW QtNetworkManager does not allow to emit `<property>Changed` signals per D-Bus property from the box.

Comment: That is why some more coding needed. I started with DBus but lost there and now it is mixed DBus and QtNetworkManager plus Qt Network.

Comment: @Orient Documentation sucks big time, that's the hardest part with the NM, since you have to understand comments like "pass the name" or get used to parameters which have totally different names in different signatures but are basically the same. Really, documentation needs so much more love. That said, linux codebase is your friend, e.g. look at [this code](https://people.debian.org/~biebl/plasma-nm/plasma-nm-0.9.3.0/declarative-plugins/handler.cpp) for WiFi creation. Similar rules applies to wired/modem connections and it is relatively easy to activate/deactivate them. Hope that's useful.

Comment: I've done Wi-Fi connections and AP management Qt Quick client. The question has been arised during refactoring process.

Comment: Oh I see. Glad to hear that @Orient! :)